# How can i use expo cli with my smartphone on termux

Tags: termux

Hello friends i'm new here.
I want to run react native project with my android but i got this error when i run expo cli on termux **Error: Platform not supported**
[error illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgo3O.png)

Ps: i use TECNO SPARK 5 Pro with Android 10

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved by reverting to version 4.2.1. Uninstall expo-cli and install expo-cli@4.2.1 .

Comment: thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

**You can create easyly by using simple trick**
First you need to install one linus operating systeam (ubantu2.0) in your termux android application
*You can easyly install ubantu os with anylinux application just download from playstore *

**After instaling the ubantu os in your android device** then you need to install nodejs in your ubantu os inaide termux just type commend **apt update && apt upgrade && apt install nodejs**
*After this commend you need to put one more command* for instaling react -native(expo)
**npm install -g expo-cli**
If you face any problem then you need to upgrade your nodejs version with letest version with using nvm
**Here is orginal documentation about letest version nodejs using nvm** *https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-nvm-and-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04/*